# Are these 2 procedures to fight cancer (cancer "vaccine", and cancer drugs which can attack all tumours) related?

Tags: cancer

Last year appeared the new of a cancer "vaccine" (not a vaccine in the traditional sense) tested in animals for 4 types of cancer and which worked in 97% of the cases to eliminate already existent tumours.

[Cancer Vaccine Trial](https://www.livescience.com/62161-cancer-vaccine-trial.html)

Now appeared the new of "cancer drugs which can attack all tumours" to be fast-tracked by NHS.

[Game changing cancer drugs can attack tumours](https://www.telegraph.co.uk/news/2019/06/18/game-changing-cancer-drugs-can-attack-tumours-will-fast-tracked/?fbclid=IwAR3BL5TsX5R6KYjciYqnGGtMJn3Rbc7WFbmOHY26yTs6KGAaPaf7zaR2d-I)

I would like to know if both procedures are based in similar ideas (meaning the second one could have a similar effectiveness to the first one) or if they are completely unrelated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first source ([Science Direct](https://www.livescience.com/62161-cancer-vaccine-trial.html)) says that the "vaccine" treatment stimulates T cells to attack cancer. In general, this treatment is intended for all tumors and has been very successful in studies in mice. [Cancer.net](https://www.cancer.net/navigating-cancer-care/how-cancer-treated/immunotherapy-and-vaccines/what-are-cancer-vaccines) and [Cancerresearchuk](https://www.cancerresearchuk.org/about-cancer/cancer-in-general/treatment/immunotherapy/types/vaccines-to-treat-cancer) describe cancer treatment vaccines in a bit more detail.

The second source ([Telegraph.co.uk](https://www.telegraph.co.uk/news/2019/06/18/game-changing-cancer-drugs-can-attack-tumours-will-fast-tracked/?fbclid=IwAR3BL5TsX5R6KYjciYqnGGtMJn3Rbc7WFbmOHY26yTs6KGAaPaf7zaR2d-I)) mentions “tumor agnostic” or "tissue agnostic" drugs, which target tumors according to their genetic make-up, rather than the tissue from which they arise. This treatment is intended only for specific tumors with known genetic mutations. Examples of tissue-agnostic drugs are [pembrolizumab](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pembrolizumab) and [larotrectinib](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Larotrectinib), which are approved by FDA for treatment of certain metastatic solid tumors.

So, these are two different ideas and most of these drugs are currently in a research phase.

Comment: in complement to Jan's answer, the 2 therapies discussed here are unrelated. The first one stimulates T cells locally at/around the tumor site with TLR ligands and is a class of **immunotherapy**, while the second one aims at shrinking the tumor cells by targeting some genetic alterations. Note that the second one may induce immunogenicity